# TFS Build with TAP

Tags: matlab, tfs, continuous-integration, tap

We are attempting to introduce continuous integration into our MATLAB environment. Now that MATLAB supports testing and TAPPlugin I am hoping to run all of my tests from command line and output to a tap file, but I am a little confused about how to make TFS Build consume the file and fail the check in if the tests did not pass.

Has anyone attempted to integrate TAP output with TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have decided to investigate TFS extensibility and are working to write our own TAP parser to work with TFS.

Inspiration found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/131635-how-can-i-integrate-the-matlab-testing-framework-with-team-foundation-server):